# How To handle ValueError?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

So here's a little guessing game where you have 9 attempts to guess a number between 0 and 100. However if the user enters a string value they get a `ValueError`. How to I handle the `ValueError`?

```
for Guesses in range(9):
        print('Take a guess.')

        Guess = int(input())

        if Guess < 0:
            print('Please enter a positive number')
        elif Guess > 100:
            print('The number is only between 0 and 100')
        elif Guess < Number:
            print('Higher...')
        elif Guess > Number:
            print('Lower...')           
        else:
            print('Spot on!')
            break # Guess was correct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try` and `except`. Try this:

```
for Guesses in range(9):
        print('Take a guess.')
        while True:
            try:
                Guess = int(input())
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Try again. That is not a number")

        if Guess < 0:
            print('Please enter a positive number')
        elif Guess > 100:
            print('The number is only between 0 and 100')
        elif Guess < Number:
            print('Higher...')
        elif Guess > Number:
            print('Lower...')           
        else:
            print('Spot on!')
            break # Guess was correct
```

A little advancement:

```
for Guesses in range(9):
        print('Take a guess.')
        while True:
            try:
                Guess = int(input())
                if (0 > Guess):
                    print('Please enter a positive number')
                elif (100 < Guess):
                    print('The number is only between 0 and 100')
                else:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print("Try again. That is not a number")
        elif Guess < Number:
            print('Higher...')
        elif Guess > Number:
            print('Lower...')           
        else:
            print('Spot on!')
            break # Guess was correct
```

Also, it is recommended that variable names shouldn't have uppercase.